# How to downgrade version from 4.5.X to 4.4.X

Tags: mattermost

I upgraded the mettermost version from 4.4.1 to 4.5.
However, I got the error...

So, I tried to downgrade the version to 4.4.1, but the mattermost said "The database schema of the older version isn't supported".
Does anyone know how we should modify the database schema.

※browser: FireFox ESR 52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't downgrade a Mattermost install to a previous version through any officially supported path. You will need to revert to the database backup from before the upgrade in order to go back to version 4.4.

However, for the specific versions in question (reverting from 4.5 to 4.4) it is possible to do a downgrade as there are no database schema changes between these two versions. You will need to run the following SQL command in your Mattermost database:

```
UPDATE Systems SET Value='4.4.0' WHERE Name='Version';
```

You should then be able to run Mattermost 4.4.1 successfully on that database.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I was able to downgrade it!